# Load GUISkin from file?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load a GUISkin from an external folder (not inside Resources) but I'm having trouble doing this.
Here is what I tried:

```
IEnumerator LoadSkin()
{
    var www = new WWW("file:///" + Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Mods"), "Internal"), "EditorSkin.guiskin"));
    yield return www;

    byte[] bytes = www.bytes;
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    GUI.skin = (GUISkin)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

But it's giving me this error:
`Exception: SerializationException: Unexpected binary element: 0`

Anyone have any idea how to load an external GUISkin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using asset bundle for this. Export your gui skin an asset bundle. To make an assetbundle [see the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildingAssetBundles.html). After that you can use the same method like this:

```
IEnumerator LoadSkin()
{
  var www = new WWW("file:///" + Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Mods"), "Internal"), "EditorSkin.unity3d"));
  yield return www;
  if (www.error != null)
        yield break;

  GUI.skin = www.assetBundle.mainAsset as GUISkin;
}
```